# Output richtext metabox value

Tags: theme-development, metabox, wp-editor

I have rich text  metabox.When I echo the out put it shows html tags.If I write `<h1>Hi</h1>` in editor metabox it ouput the same.My works so far

```
     <?php
     $valueeee2=  get_post_meta($_GET['post'], 'SMTH_METANAME_VALUE' , true ) ;
     wp_editor( htmlspecialchars_decode($valueeee2), 'mettaabox_ID_stylee', $settings =     array('textarea_name'=>'MyInputNAME',) );
     ?>
```

To display

```
$content=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'SMTH_METANAME_VALUE', true);
echo $content;
```

Comment: What is the question here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `echo html_entity_decode($ccontent)` .